# How to find multiple words in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to take a users search input and find records that match in SQL.

I'm currently using `Name like '%' + @SearchText + '%' )` which works fine if they enter in the text the correct way.

Example

If they search for `"Jaws Revenge"` or `"Jaws 2 the revenge"` or `"revenge jaws"` they won't get any results. I want it to return 1 result, id #2 from the table below.

```
Movies Table
---------------------
ID  Name
1   Jaws
2   Jaws 2: The revenge
3   Jaws 3-D
4   Rocky 5000
```

I've read about full text search but I don't know if that's worth it, the only option, or if there is a more simple solution.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.  You should tag your questions with the database you are actually using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the tip!

Comment: As per your comment in Gordon's answer, you need `FULLTEXT` Index

Comment: @Pரதீப் Can you provide an example or link? Also, is that available on cloud hosting like AWS or Azure?

Comment: It is available in Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql

Comment: @Pரதீப் I ended up using full text search and it seems to solve this problem but has now caused a few others. Post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

You can replace spaces with `%`:

```
Name like '%' + replace(@SearchText, ' ', '%') + '%'
```

Comment: This is getting closer but it doesn't work for searches like `revenge jaws`. I know the OP didn't state that case, sorry. I updated the op

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like '%' + replace(@SearchText, ' ', '%') + '%'`  in expration